# How to import mapbox-gl-draw into Angular 2/4?

Tags: angular, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am importing the module in my Angular 2/4 app like this:

```
import { MapboxDraw } from '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw/dist/mapbox-gl-draw';
```

and using it in one of the components like this:

```
var draw = new MapboxDraw({
   displayControlsDefault: false,
   controls: {
     polygon: true,
     trash: true
   }
});

map.addControl(draw);
```

but I am getting an error when I open the page:

```
ERROR TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__mapbox_mapbox_gl_draw_dist_mapbox_gl_draw__.MapboxDraw is not a constructor
```

What is the best way to import mapbox-gl-draw?

Comment: check this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-mapbox) might help

Comment: Hi Rahul, I managed to get mapbox-gl to work but I cannot say the same for mapbox-draw-gl.

Answer (score 7):

This is a minimal example app that works on my machine: It is based on this little project on github: https://github.com/haoliangyu/ngx-mapboxgl-starter

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';
import * as MapboxDraw from 'mapbox-gl-draw';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  ngOnInit() {
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'your Token';
    let map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',
      zoom: 5,
      center: [-78.880453, 42.897852]
    });

    let Draw = new MapboxDraw();

    map.addControl(Draw)

    map.on('load', function() {
      // ALL YOUR APPLICATION CODE
    });
  }
}
```

```css
#map {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id='map'></div>
```

Note that I am using `'mapbox-gl-draw'` instead of `'@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw'`. So you might wanna try installing this package via `npm install mapbox-gl-draw`. I tried the later one but this throws an error for me. Also don't forget to add the required mapbox-gl-draw CSS.

Comment: Hi, I tried using the require function but unfortunately it does not work as I think this has got to do with the fact that this is an Angular 2 app.

Comment: @AfeezAziz My answer said you should use `import { MapboxDraw } from '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw';` and not require. The important part is that the path is different to your initial one.

Comment: Hi, if that is the case, then it still does not work unfortunately. The change of `'@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw';` to `'@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw/dist/mapbox-gl-draw';` is because I was following the instruction for mapbox-gl which works.

Comment: @AfeezAziz I updated my answer with an example. Can you try this solution?

Answer (score 3):

i have install `npm install @mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw`

added css into angular-cli.json

```
"../node_modules/@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw/dist/mapbox-gl-draw.css",
```

**Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';
import * as MapboxDraw from '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  static t;
  ngOnInit() {
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'Token';
    AppComponent.t.map= new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',
      zoom: 5,
      center: [-78.880453, 42.897852]
    });

     const draw = new MapboxDraw({
        displayControlsDefault: false,
        controls: {
            polygon: true,
            trash: true
        }
    });
    AppComponent.t.map.addControl(draw);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the dependency using:

> npm i --save-dev @types/mapbox__mapbox-gl-draw

Add the below import to your component:

import * as MapboxDraw from '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw';